# gulp.dest not creating destination folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

My gulp code looks like this, in part

```
gulp.src(['../application-base/**/**.js', '!../application-base/assets/**/**.js'], { base: './' })
    .pipe(gulpPlumber({
        errorHandler: function (error) {
            console.log(`\nError ${error}`);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gprint(filePath => "Transpiling: " + filePath.replace('..\\application-base\\', '')))
    .pipe(babel({ compact: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled/'))
    .on('end', () => done());
```

If I change

`.pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled/'))`

to

`.pipe(gulp.dest(''))`

then the transpiled files are created, and overwrite the originals.  The problem is that

`.pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled/'))`

does not save the file, with the same original path, under `application-base-transpiled`

As you can see, I am using a base, which seems to work otherwise.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I looked more closely, and it seems even with

`.pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled/'))`

Gulp is still placing the transpiled files into the original place, overwriting the original.  There's something about the dest I'm passing that Gulp doesn't like, and is ignoring silently.

**EDIT 2**

It seems *removing* the `base` option solves this problem, contrary to advice I've seen elsewhere.  The docs for `gulp.dest` don't really discuss this.

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

**EDIT 3**

Per Sven's answer, I tried this

```
gulp.src(['**/**.js', '!assets/**/**.js'], { base: '../application-base' })
    .pipe(gulpPlumber({
        errorHandler: function errorHandler(error) {
            console.log('\nError ' + error);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gprint(filePath => "Transpiling: " + filePath.replace('..\\application-base\\', '')))
    .pipe(babel({ compact: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled/'))
    .on('end', () => done());
```

But it seems the base is being ignored, and the files from my own current directory are being grabbed and transpiled in place (the last thing I want - fortunately GIT was helpful in undoing the damage).

Is the base parameter ignored when using an array for `src`?

Comment: It's really weird, can you try `./../application-base-transpiled`? The `{ base: './' }` will tell gulp to preserve the entire relative path.

Comment: @Tom - fortunately that had no effect - would have been *really* bizarre if it did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In gulp streams the destination path of a file follows this pseudo-equation:

**`gulp.dest` + (`gulp.src` without leading `base`) = dest path of file**

Example:

```
gulp.src('src/js/foo.js', {base:'src/'}).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

Result:

**`'dist/'` + (`'src/js/foo.js'` without leading `'src/'`)  = `'dist/js/foo.js'`**

In your case:

**`'../application-base-transpiled/'` + (`'../application-base/foo/bar.js'` without leading `'./'`) = `'../application-base-transpiled/../application-base/foo/bar.js'`**

So your files end up in the original directory.

You have to pass `{base: '../application-base/'}` to `gulp.src()` to make your example work.

---

**NOTE**

You still need to include `'../application-base/'` in your `src` path. The purpose of `base` is to manipulate the dest path, per my equation above; it does *not* serve the purpose of lessening the number of keystrokes you type in `gulp.src`.  So the end result should be something like this

```
gulp.src(['../application-base/**/**.js'], { base: '../application-base' })
        .pipe(gulpPlumber({
            errorHandler: function errorHandler(error) {
                console.log('\nError ' + error);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gprint(filePath => "Transpiling: " + filePath.replace('..\\application-base\\', '')))
        .pipe(babel({ compact: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../application-base-transpiled'))
        .on('end', () => done());
```

---

If you don't pass a [`base` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) to `gulp.src()` a default is set:

> Default: everything before a glob starts (see [glob2base](https://github.com/contra/glob2base))

What this means is that everything up to the first `**` or `*` in the pattern that you pass to `gulp.src()` is used as the `base` option. Since your pattern is `../application-base/**/**.js`, your `base` option automatically becomes `../application-base/`.