# Gulp (gulp.dest() not working) is not creating folder, nor putting any files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, gulp

Gulp is literally not creating any files or folder even if the script runs. And there is no error messages in the console. How could i debug this?

Here is my **gulpfile.js**:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');

const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const lodash = require('lodash');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

const folder = {
    src: "src/main/resources/assets/", // source assets files
    dist: "build/resources/main/assets/" //build assets files
};

function copyAssets(done) {
    var required_assets = {
        js: [
            // ...
        ],
        scss: [
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "./node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.css"
        ],
    };

    //copying required assets
    lodash(required_assets).forEach(function(assets, type) {
        // console.log(assets); // can see both the arrays
        if (type == "scss") {
            gulp.src(assets)
                .pipe(rename({
                    // rename aaa.css to _aaa.scss
                    prefix: "_",
                    extname: ".scss"
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.src + "scss/vendor"));  // not copying
        } else {
            gulp.src(assets).pipe(gulp.dest(folder.src + "js/vendor"));  // not copying
        }
    });

    done();
}

function css() {
    gulp
        .src([folder.src + "scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss"]) // this isn't even created and throws error
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass()) // scss to css
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ["last 2 versions"]
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({
            // rename bootstrap.css to bootstrap.min.css
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./")) // source maps for bootstrap.min.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.dist + "css/"));

    // other css tasks
}

gulp.task(
    "default",
    gulp.series(
        copyAssets,
        // ... other tasks
        css,
        // ...
    )
);
```

**This is the console logs:**

```js
[12:01:59] Using gulpfile /mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/gulpfile.js
[12:01:59] Starting 'default'...
[12:01:59] Starting 'copyAssets'...
[12:01:59] Finished 'copyAssets' after 67 ms
//... other tasks
[12:01:59] Starting 'css'...
[12:01:59] 'css' errored after 18 ms
[12:01:59] Error: File not found with singular glob: /mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/src/main/resources/assets/scss/vendor/_bootstrap.scss (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at Glob.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob-stream/readable.js:84:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Glob.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Glob._finish (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)
    at done (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)
    at Glob._processSimple2 (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:688:12)
    at /mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:676:10
    at Glob._stat2 (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:772:12)
    at lstatcb_ (/mnt/d/Downloads/Applications/Projects/Extraction/node_modules/glob/glob.js:764:12)
[12:01:59] 'default' errored after 196 ms
```

I've tried

- [gulp.dest not creating destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631746/gulp-dest-not-creating-destination-folder/36632845)
- [Gulp doesn't create folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360885/gulp-doesnt-create-folder)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug

Comment: @Ravenous gulp actually didn't ran there, there was no output from that function other function are running properly how could i fix that?

Comment: Its been fixed, actually i have to return the combined stream which i did using help of merge-stream npm package .